# How to solve the limitation of AWS Redshift super type querying

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a problem with AWS Redshift nested data super type navigation

```
SELECT
    a.b.c[0]
FROM
    table
```

Return me

```
sample output 1
{"d":"Some String","e":"date and time"}    
sample output 2
{"d":"Some String","e":"date and time"}
```

when I query

```
SELECT
    a.b.c[0].d
FROM
    table
```

Return me

```
Some String
Some String
```

which is expected but when I try to query

```
SELECT
    a.b.c[0].e
FROM
    table
```

Return me

```
Null
Null
```

I know this is the limitation of AWS Redshift but how do I solve this kind of error?
Any advise and help is appreciated.

I also try un-nested the query such as

```
Create table new_table(qwer super);
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT a.b.c[0]
FROM table
```

and try query it such as above

```
SELECT
    qwee.d
FROM
    new_table
```

Return me

```
Some String
Some String
```

```
SELECT
    qwer.e
FROM
    new_table
```

Return me

```
Null
Null
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a limitation? Your query to return `e` should work fine.

Comment: By right the query of `e` should return me 
`date and time`
but it return me `NULL`